# Prove if the linear transformation $T$ is injective, $T^{-1}:T(V) \to V$ is a linear operator

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, linear-transformations

Problem:

Let $V$ and $W$ be vector spaces over a field $F$ and $T:V \to W$ a linear transformation. Show:

1) $T(V)$ is a subspace of $V$

2) If $T$ is an injection, $T^{-1}:T(V) \to V$ is a linear operator.

Solution for (1):

Let $W \ni w_1 = T(v_1)$, where $v_1 \in V$, and let $W \ni w_2 = T(v_2)$, where $v_2 \in V$.

If we sum the terms, we get $w_1 + w_2 = T(v_1) + T(v_2) = T(v_1 + v_2)$. Since $v_1, v_2 \in V$, and $V$ is a vector space, then $v_1 + v_2 \in V$, then $T(v_1 + v_2) \in T(V)$.

Let $W \ni w = T(v)$, and $a \in F$ where $F$ is a field, and $v \in V$, where $V$ is a vector space.
We can multiply, $aw = aT(v)=T(av)$. Since $v$ is a vector, $av \in V$, so $T(av)\in T(V)$.

I have tried to do (2) but I cannot come with a solution.

Comment: if you have tried, you should also write what you tried, this is helpful (for you, and for answerers)

Comment: hint: if $T$ is an injection on $W$ then it is a bijection on $T(V)$.

Answer (score 0):

Your proof of $(1)$ is good. For $(2)$, let $w_1,w_2\in T(V)$. Then

$$T(T^{-1}(w_1+w_2))=w_1+w_2=T(T^{-1}(w_1))+T(T^{-1}(w_2))=T(T^{-1}(w_1)+T^{-1}(w_2)).$$

Now how can you use the fact that $T$ is injective?

Answer (score 0):

Note that $T$ is a bijection, and  $T^{-1} \circ T=id_{V}$. let $x,y \in W$ so that $T(v)=x$ and $T(u)=y$. Well, then

$ T^{-1}(\alpha x+y)=T^{-1}(T(\alpha v+u))=\alpha v+u=\alpha T^{-1}(x)+T^{-1}(y).$

[For the last equality, note that $T(v)=x \implies v=T^{-1}(x)$, and likewise for $y$.]